# Two dimensional and three dimensional array relations

Tags: arrays

For the array int array[2][3][4];

```
i) array[0][0] == &array[0][0][0]
ii) array[0][1] == array[0][0][1]
iii) array[0][1]== &array[0][0][0]
```

Looks o me like nothing is equals

Comment: what are you asking? you should draw a picture out to help you solve these kind of questions

Comment: can you formulate it as a question?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `i)` is a valid statement. Both sides of the equality point to the address of the first element in the 3d array.

Comment: But the lefthand side is a two dimensional array

Answer (score 0):

Trying to understand your question. Let guess you are talking about an array of integer in C:

```
int array[2][3][4];
```

1. is true: array[0][0] and &array[0][0][0] are the same address.
2. You are comparing a pointer to an integer (or whatever the type of your array). It should not compile.
3. is false, this is valid because you are comparing an int* to an int*. But it's clearly not the same address.

   ```
   array[0][0] is the address of array[0][0][0] but not of array[0][1][0]
   array[0][1] is the address of array[0][1][0]
   etc...
   ```

Remember that:

```
array is of type int***
array[0] is of type int**
array[0][0] is of type int*
array[0][0][0] is of type int
```